# How to make status bar Transparent in flutter?

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

The one of the solution which I have found for it.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
        SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
```

Comment: ok, so what is the error or issue .?

Comment: It works for me but I am concer for should I go for flutter plugin or make use of service dart. which is the better approach

Comment: It's Totally Fine -  importing `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Comment: Because I am also concern to importing packages which increases the APK bundling size.

Comment: use - `import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show SystemChrome, SystemUiOverlayStyle;` then.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the one you've found is actually a better solution. You can check it from the [Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html).

> **setSystemUIOverlayStyle method**
>
> ```
> void setSystemUIOverlayStyle (
> SystemUiOverlayStyle style
> )
> ```
>
> Specifies the style to use for the system overlays that are visible
> (if any).

I've written a basic example to check how it looks.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Regarding the size, it seems that using the Flutter built-in solution is a better practice than using 3rd party plugins. There are also some things that you can do to reduce the size of your application. Check [this blog](https://suryadevsingh24032000.medium.com/size-matters-reducing-flutter-app-size-best-practices-ca992207782) for some tips. To summarize, these are the listed items in the said blog that you need to optimize:

> 1. Image Asset
> 2. Use Google Fonts
> 3. Icons
> 4. Dynamic App Delivery
> 5. Cache
> 6. Proguard
> 7. Use Specific Libraries

In the documentation, you can check about "[Measuring your app's size](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size)". As most of the developers are concerned with the size of the app so Flutter made this documentation available.